# What is the main difference between interior and exterior inverse problem?

Tags: inverse-problems

I wonder whether there is any difference between interior inverse problem and exterior inverse problem
with respect to stability, numerical solution or anything.. Is it harder to solve interior inverse problem than exterior inverse problem ? What are their difficulties ?

Any answer is appreciated. Thanks in advance.